# Retrieve id from AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity as follows:

```
public class PaletteColor
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ColorId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Index("ColorCodeIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public int ColorInt { get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to write a method which will `AddOrUpdate` an entity and return the `ColorId` from the object which was saved.

```
public int AddOrUpdateColor(string ColorCode, int ColorInt)
{
    db.ColorPalletteColors.AddOrUpdate(
        c => c.ColorCode,
        new ColorPaletteColor 
        {
            ColorCode = ColorCode,
            ColorInt = ColorInt
        });

    db.SaveChanges();

    return c.; //Shall return the ColorId here.
}
```

I'm not quite sure about the approach, I would like to return an id from the saved object but can not point to it.

Comment: Does the AddOrUpdate come with Entity Framework?

Comment: @Glubus I try it the first time, I guess it's a new extension on ef 6 [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: I see, it's part of an extension library. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the object to a variable first:

```
public int AddOrUpdateColor(string ColorCode, int ColorInt)
{
    var color = new ColorPaletteColor 
        {
            ColorCode = ColorCode,
            ColorInt = ColorInt
        };

    db.ColorPalletteColors.AddOrUpdate(c => c.ColorCode, color);   
    db.SaveChanges();

    return color.ColorId; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Id` will be automatically filled for you if you first assign it to a variable:

```
public int AddOrUpdateColor(string ColorCode, int ColorInt)
{
    var colorPaletteColor = new ColorPaletteColor 
        {
            ColorCode = ColorCode,
            ColorInt = ColorInt
        };

    db.ColorPalletteColors.AddOrUpdate(c => c.ColorCode, colorPaletteColor);   
    db.SaveChanges();

    return colorPaletteColor.ColorId; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int AddOrUpdateColor(string ColorCode, int ColorInt)
{
    var color = db.ColorPalletteColors.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ColorCode == ColorCode);
    if (color == null)
    {
       color = new ColorPaletteColor()
       {
          ColorCode = ColorCode;
       };
       db.ColorPaletteColors.AddObject(color);

    }
    color.ColorInt = ColorInt;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return color.ColorId; //Shall return the ColorId here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that `c.ColorId` should be filled with the ***generated ID***, so you could return it directly.

Use a `var` in the method to do so...